# I'm trying to check a checkbox but its resulting in a stale elemnt exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The entire page has gone a front end change and it looks like this problem has started after this change. I'm gonna share the image of HTML -http://screencast.com/t/JDTai6cku. The solution is not working with locator ID, perhaps another locator like CSS may work.

and here is the code i'm trying where there is just a login cal before getting the desired URL

```
 def Manage(self):         
    self.login()
    driver=self.driver
    driver.get('<>')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    elem=driver.find_element_by_id("stage-check-all")
    #This is the point when it throws the exception
    elem.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

and here is the exception i'm facing as a result -

self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: u'Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up'

Comment: So it does have an ID...? ....`<input id="stage-check-all>`....`id="stage-check-all"`.....? No....?

Comment: but this id doesn't seem belong with my check box "Select all" and above code is not working with this id too.

Comment: So what happens? It doesn't click it? Throws an error? What?

Comment: It is throwing this exception -
Message: u'Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up' ; Stacktrace:

Comment: So why did you not include that exception in the post? Showing us the exception we can see that it's nothing to do with your selector or locator. You are having stale element problems.

Comment: ok Arran i will take care of it next time.now what should i do to solve this

Comment: Well the exception means the DOM changes, in *some* way. Is there any animation that goes on in the page?

Answer (score 1):

**Mistake #1:**

The `<input>` tag is not closed with a corresponding `</input>` tag.

Do you have access to this HTML code? If yes, then you should fix this problem.

**Mistake #2:**

Function `click()` does not return a web-element.

You can either do:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("stage-check-all").click()
```

Or do:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("stage-check-all")
elem.click()
```

**But even after fixing these mistakes, the exception you're describing will most likely sustain.**

A `StaleElementReferenceException` means that something has changed in the DOM **after** you've loaded the page with `driver.get(url)`. So there is something in between `driver.get(url)` and `driver.find_element_by_id("stage-check-all").click()` that you are not telling us about.

Publish your code and I might be able to answer your question...

Comment: I did an update to my question with the code I'm trying, please see you can help me now..

Comment: If you provide the argument that you're passing to `driver.get()`, then I might be able to help

Comment: ok Barak, can you please tell how can I contact you to show you the actual URL and the web page i'm working on.

Comment: How about publishing it here?